# how the keyword in works in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I know how to use the keyword `in` in OCaml.  My question is in which order the compilator execute the expression.

For example let's take the following code :

```
let v = expr1 in expr2
```

The compilator looks first at `expr2`, and then when `v` appears in `expr2` it replaces `v` by `expr1`? 
Or first, it evaluates `expr1` and then apply `expr2` ?

You may wonder why I am asking this weird question. This is due to the fact that I do not understand how the following code works :

```
let rec some_function = function 
   | [] -> () 
   | t::q when (*here put a condition*) -> some_function q
   | t::q -> (*some operations here*); some_function q
in 
let s = (*some list*)
some_function s
```

How does this code work? 
I mean when we have the recursive call `some_function q` then does the program directly goes in the `in` block and apply the other recursive call `some_function s`?

Comment: `some_function s` is not a recursive call. Why would the program go to the `in` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the program says `let v = expr1 in expr2`, OCaml first evaluates `expr1`, and then begins the evaluation of `expr2` in an environment in which `v` is associated to the value that was obtained as result of `expr1`.

This evaluation strategy, [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value), is not the only one possible, but it is the strategy that OCaml use.

Now let us consider the snippet:

```
let rec some_function = function ...
in
let s = (*some list*)
some_function s
```

When the program contains the snippet above, the following steps take place:

- `function ...` is evaluated. This step is short because evaluating a `function ...` block does not mean that the code inside `...` is evaluated. Instead, the result of the evaluation of `function ...` is a closure (forgetting about optimizations that apply in your example but not in general).
- the code represented by `(*some list*)` is evaluated in an environment in which `some_function` is bound to the closure discussed above.
- the expression `some_function s` is evaluated in an environment where `some_function` is bound to a closure and `s` is bound to the result of the evaluation of `(*some list*)`. In this environment, this evaluation succeeds and the closure gets applied, which means that the code that defined `some_function` will now be executed (in an environment where its argument has been provided).

A closure is made of unevaluated code and a partial environment. The environment only needs to be augmented with an additional binding for the argument in order to contain everything needed to evaluate the code. On the other hand, as long as the argument has not been provided, evaluation cannot start because the function's body refers to the argument.

The fact that `some_function` is recursive does not change the general scheme. It only means that when the body of the closure is evaluated, the environment also contains a binding associating the same `some_function` to the closure, so that a call to `some_closure` inside the body is treated the same way it would be outside the body.

Comment: Thank you, it's very clear. So it means that `some_function` is evaluated as a closure only once (the first time), then `some_function` is evaluated (with the `s` argument the first time), and then when we finished evaluating `some_function` we directly go in the `in` block and we evaluate `some_function s` on so on on so forth. So we have  : **1**- `some_function` is a closure **2**-now using the closure we can evaluate `some_function s` **3**- we've finished evaluating `some_function s` so we go in the `in` block and reevaluate `some_function s` 4- ... we evaluate `some_function s` forever

Comment: Actually, I think I am wrong. After using some tests and rereading your answer I think it does the following : **1-** `some_function` is evaluated as a closure **2-** using the closure we go in the `in` block and evaluate: `some_function s` and that's it. So at each new call we are not going to evaluate what is happening in the `in` block. We evaluate what is in the `in` block only once.

Comment: @obla yes to your second comment. Adding side-effects such as `print_endline "here"` allows to see when and how many times code is visited.